# How to set Websocketpp buffer size?

Tags: c++

I would like to set the max buffer size for servers and client to 10 messages only. So that the Websocketpp will discard any messages, if the buffer exceeds 10 messages.

how can I discard all the messages in the buffer using websocketpp code?
Thanks

Comment: I don't see how this could be possible given that Websockets run over TCP. In any case you have mis-described your problem. You don't want to set the buffer size, you want to limit the number of pending messages.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the documentation, which you can find here:
https://docs.websocketpp.org/reference_8config.html

It seems that you can only limit the size of each message using ***max_message_size***, but not the total number of messages.

You can also try to use ***connection_read_buffer_size*** for reducing the read buffer size to optimize for small messages, if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: **reducing the read buffer size to optimize for small messages** This is not op looking for.  OP wants the total buffer size which seems impossible.

Comment: @StriveSun Exactly, I just tried to provide some kind of an alternative.